# Create a list of rules built from data set fields

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, associations, rule

I want to convert a dataset to a list of features and a list of target values, for use in `Predict` and also more generally. I know `Predict` can accept datasets natively but there are some "features" with `Predict` in V10.1, that require dropping back to lists and rules. The dataset is :

```
ds = 
  {<|"age" -> 4, "weight" -> 10, "gender" -> "M", 
     "comment" -> "mummy says I eat like a horse", "result" -> 1.4|>,
   <|"age" -> 4, "weight" -> 8, "gender" -> "M", 
     "comment" -> "throws his porridge on the floor", "result" -> 2.3|>,
   <|"age" -> 5, "weight" -> 15, "gender" -> "F", 
     "comment" -> "loves green vegetables", "result" -> 3.5|>,
   <|"age" -> 7, "weight" -> 30, "gender" -> "F", 
    "comment" -> "Thinks chocolate is fantastic", "result" -> 5.1|>} //
  Dataset
```

I thought `MapThread` might work :

```
MapThread[Rule, {Values[Normal[ds[All, {"age", "weight"}]]], 
Values[Normal[ds[All, {"result"}]]]}, 2]
```

The end result I am Looking for is of the form

> ```
> {{4, 10}  -> 1.4}, {4, 8} -> 2.3} ... }
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it:

```
ds[All, {#age, #weight, #gender} -> #result &] // Normal
```

> `{{4, 10, "M"} -> 1.4, {4, 8, "M"} -> 2.3, {5, 15, "F"} -> 
>     3.5, {7, 30, "F"} -> 5.1}`

Comment: You beat me to the punch but my formulation is slightly different so I posted anyway. +1 of course.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard +1, it's good to have both approaches represented.

Comment: More learnt about dataset.  Thanx to both.  This seems the most "datasety" answer so accepted

Answer (score 4):

```
{#age, #weight} -> #result & /@ ds // Normal
```

> ```
> {{4, 10} -> 1.4, {4, 8} -> 2.3, {5, 15} -> 3.5, {7, 30} -> 5.1}
> ```